# Update TIMESTAMP value using WHERE to determine time zone

Tags: oracle

A developer has written data to my database that has the incorrect timezone format. Instead of an hours offset it has the name as seen here:

```
18-NOV-16 12.17.41.000000000 PM -05:00
18-NOV-16 12.17.05.000000000 PM -05:00
18-NOV-16 12.16.07.000000000 PM AMERICA/NEW_YORK
18-NOV-16 12.12.54.000000000 PM -05:00
18-NOV-16 12.12.33.000000000 PM -05:00
```

The column in question is of type `TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIMEZONE`. Another 3rd party application is crashing reading these records as it apparently is not coded to handle the long-form timezone.

Researching here, I have found the correct update query to correct this:

```
UPDATE <<your table>>    
SET <<your timestamp column>> = <<your timestamp column>> AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

The problem is I have 500K+ records and don't want to update the entire table when only a few hundred rows are involved (due to replication that takes place after the update). How would I use a `WHERE` clause to only get the rows that are stored with the inappropriate timezone data? I've read all over and can't find an example that shows filtering results by the format of the timezone.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What type is columne where you store that? Is it varchar2?

Comment: Why do you consider 'America/New_York' as wrong?

Comment: it's TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIMEZONE. I will edit the question to add this.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Another app that access the data is crashing trying to read those rows as it's not correctly handling the `AMERICA/NEW_YORK` versus `-05:00`. I have no control over the development of that app so correcting this is my only route.

Comment: Do you like to update all times to UTC or +04:00?

Comment: I'd like to update to -05:00 not UTC -- assuming the update query would be changed to `AT TIME ZONE '-05:00'` ?

Comment: Maybe you should revise this app and run `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI:SS AM TZH:TZM'` or query your database with `TO_CHAR(<<your timestamp column>>, 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI:SS AM TZH:TZM')`. Then it should work also with time zones like `AMERICA/NEW_YORK`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have data with me to test, but try this:

```
where extract(timezone_region from date_column) <> 'UNKNOWN'
```

I think that when you use this function, and it only has number value (not the region) it returns you 'UNKNOWN'